# Image steganography Using C#

Tags: c#, steganography

I want to add some text such as "Manula", to the image using Stenography and want to save it. And also i want to retrieve it again. I want to made this project using C#.

Can anyone send me the C# code for this programm.

Thanks..

Comment: "I want to make this project using C#", "Can anyone send me the C# code for this programme". I see a slight contradiction there...

Comment: Asking for assistance is one thing but asking for somebody to write the code for you is another. This may be a language issue but you come off sounding like you want somebody to do your work for you.

Comment: No. What I mean here is give some guide lines. Not to write the program. Sorry for the inconvenience happens.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort on your part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Image-Steganography.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What You Need Is Here.......... http://www.programmer2programmer.net/live_projects/project_7/steganography.aspx