# how to hide my custom data in image programatically c#

Tags: c#

please guide me how to hide my custom data in image. i want to generate a image and hide my custom data in image and read back that data from image later. please need idea how to do it.

Comment: It's called steganography. I think you should put in some more effort into this and then come back with a real programming question.

Comment: How "hidden" should the data be, how much data do you have, how should  the image look like, like a photo, or would a [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) be enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image Steganography](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798158/image-steganography), [Image steganography Using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998531/image-steganography-using-c), [How can you hide information inside a jpg or gif photo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216156/how-can-you-hide-information-inside-a-jpg-or-gif-photo)

Answer (score 1):

You could read the format of bitmap image file, open bmp file, identify where the data starts and in the data portion put your data such that each character represents a pixel in image. I am talking about bmp image because its uncompressed format and easy to read.